# Has any jurisdiction banned the use of internal combustion engine vehicle, either now or in the future?

Tags: climate-change, transportation

I'm wondering if any place (city, country, etc.) has planned the end of the use of ICE vehicle - for professional and/or personal use - in a legally binding way (i.e. not just a vague promise but something that will take effect if not otherwise stopped).

Comment: It's discussed in the EU but not yet as a law anywhere as far as I know. Discussed dates are 2035 or something like this. And it's also just a selling ban of new ones I think.

Comment: Indeed, and I've heard that Paris is planning on banning ICE cars by 2030, but as far as I know nothing has officially been set.

Comment: a number of jurisdictions have announced bans on ICE *sales* in the future.  but not *use*.

Comment: Related: [Which countries, regions, or cities have set a date to ban the sale of gasoline and diesel vehicles?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/9862/3379)

Comment: At risk of being pedantic, jurisdictions that prohibit all motorised vehicles don’t count, do they?

Comment: Interesting related reading [Equal rights for gasoline and electricity? The dismantling of fossil fuel vehicle phase-out policy in Taiwan](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2214629622000767) "**This paper provides a rare case study of mobility transition when two-wheel vehicles are dominant**, and offer implications to countries in similar contexts."

Answer (score 7):

According to the Wikipdia article ["Mackinac Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mackinac_Island#Transportation)  On Mackinac Island (Michigan):

> Motorized vehicles have been prohibited on the island since 1898,<sup>[1]</sup> with the exception of city emergency vehicles (ambulance, police cars and fire trucks), city service vehicles and snowmobiles during winter.

I think several other small resort areas in North America, and perhaps elsewhere, have similar restrictions in place.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Car-free_zones_in_the_United_States lists 18 "car-free zones" but not all of the pages contain good sources for this.

### Notes

[1] ["What happened to a place in Michigan when cars were banned for 115 years?"](http://www.bikede.org/2013/02/26/the-isle-of-bike/#page-content) Bike Delaware

Comment: Does this answer the question, which was specifically about ICE-powerdled vehicles?

Comment: @bishop If ICE is included in all motorized vehicles than yes. However this example still allowed for ICE emergency vehicles so maybe no. But over time this question is likely only to be getting more and more answers. I'll come back in 10 years and see what I can say.

Comment: The first link opens just on the picture of a yacht with internal combustion engine. The question was about banning the engine not just a single type of vehicle using that engine.

Comment: @bishop  According to the article, Mackinac Island  has not totally banned ICE, but has severely restricted them. It seems to me that this is relevant, even if it is not a total ban.

Comment: @FluidCode
 see my comment above to bishop

Comment: I think the same is also true for Adalar (Prince islands) of Istanbul.

Comment: +1  There is also a Wikipedia page for car-free places around the world: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_car-free_places

Answer (score 3):

Zermatt, a ski resort town in Switzerland, bans ICE vehicles, but allows businesses to have electric vehicles. See [This town banned cars (except tiny electric ones)](https://youtube.com/watch?v=R2oD1ZHNMFE) by Tom Scott.

Answer (score 2):

[Tresco in the Channel Islands (UK) is car-free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tresco,_Isles_of_Scilly#Transport)

> Tresco is a car-free island. Electric vehicles are used to transport
> overnight visitors to and from Tresco Heliport and from the various
> quays, and a few golf carts are available for disabled visitors.

[Tresco](https://www.tresco.co.uk/the-island) is 297 hectares in size with a population of around 175 (in 2011) and is administered for the Crown by the Duchy of Cornwall.  It is leased to the Dorrien-Smith estate, which runs it as a timeshare business. The Dorrien-Smith family held the position of Lord Proprietors of the Scilly Islands between 1834 and 1920. I believe the ban has been in place for many years and was not originally due to climate change.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://entdecke-deutschland.de/en/favorite-places/quiet-and-children-friendly-car-free-island-in-the-north-and-east-sea/) is the overview of multiple car free islands in North and Baltic seas.

These islands are small enough that using cars as typical would not make much benefit. Heligoland even bans also bicycles [(source)](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stvo_2013/__50.html). Simply everything is easily accessible on foot.